# While changing things in localizations . tab bar Controller selected index raising NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Not possible to remove variable
0: objective{id: 13885} == {objective 0x282894500: <1100:60.5, 750:1437.22, 252:200, 251:-261008, 250:-64924.5, 249:-130482, 248:-22.5> + <750:-1, 250:1>*0x28289b570.marker{id: 13975, var: 90} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x282ff42a0.negError{id: 14445, var: 427} + <1100:-0.5>*0x282ff01e0.posErrorMarker{id: 14312, var: 398} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x282ff4780.negError{id: 14457, var: 343} + <1100:-0.5, 250:-1>*0x282894190.marker{id: 14182, var: 297} + <249:1>*0x2828939d0.marker{id: 14135, var: 250} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x282ffbf60.posErrorMarker{id: 14218, var: 312} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x282ff0000.negError{id: 14223, var: 317} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x282ff0a20.posErrorMarker{id: 14332, var: 418} + <251:1>*0x282ffef40.posErrorMarker{id: 14232, var: 326} + <1100:1>*0x282880f50.marker{id: 13907}.brokenNegError{id: 18762, var: 465} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x282fff120.negError{id: 14243, var: 337} + <252:-1>*0x28289bf70:UISV-canvas-connection.marker{id: 14288, var: 381} + <251:1>*0x282fff060.posErrorMarker{id: 14238, var: 332} + <251:2>*0x2828928f0.marker{id: 14043, var: 160} + <249:1>*0x282ff47e0.posErrorMarker{id: 14458, var: 344} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x282ff0900.negError{id: 14327, var: 413} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x282ffbf00.posErrorMarker{id: 14216, var: 310} + <750:-1>*0x2828931b0.marker{id: 14088, var: 202} + <251:-1>*0x282892030.marker{id: 14006, var: 122} + <750:1>*0x2828938e0.marker{id: 14129, var: 243} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x282ff4600.negError{id: 14449, var: 447} + <251:1>*0x282891720.marker{id: 13973, var: 88} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x282ff1200.posErrorMarker{id: 14356, var: 442} + <251:4.90497e-07, 250:-1>*0x2828930c0.marker{id: 14081, var: 196} + <250:2>*0x282891590.marker{id: 13972, var: 86} + <251:0.00277778>*UILabel:0x116264bb0.Width{id: 14149, var: 262} + <750:0.21875>*0x28289af30.marker{id: 13887, var: 3} + <1100:2>*0x282891310.marker{id: 13967}.brokenNegError{id: 18767, var: 470} + <251:-1>*0x2828907d0.marker{id: 13957, var: 73} + <250:1>*0x282893cf0.marker{id: 14156, var: 272} + <1100:2.42194e-08, 750:0.21875, 250:0.4>*0x282892e90.marker{id: 14074, var: 188} + <252:1>*0x28289bed0:UISV-canvas-connection.marker{id: 14284, var: 309} + <750:-1, 250:0.85>*0x282894050.marker{id: 14176, var: 290} + <251:2>*0x282ff45a0.posErrorMarker{id: 14460, var: 430} + <751:1, 252:1>*0x282fff7e0.negError{id: 14273, var: 368} + <251:1, 250:1>*0x28289b070.marker{id: 13890, var: 5} + <250:-1>*0x282893d90.marker{id: 14160, var: 231} + <750:1, 251:-1>*0x282ff0180.negError{id: 14227, var: 321} + <750:-1>*0x282895720:UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height.marker{id: 14499, var: 458} + <750:1, 249:1>*0x282ff4480.negError{id: 14441, var: 363} + <750:1, 250:-1>*0x282893660.marker{id: 14116, var: 230} + <251:2>*0x282893020.marker{id: 14080, var: 194} + <250:-1>*0x282893570.marker{id: 14113, var: 227} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x282fff9c0.negError{id: 14281, var: 377} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x282fff960.posErrorMarker{id: 14278, var: 373} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x282ff0b40.posErrorMarker{id: 14336, var: 422} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x282ff0f60.posErrorMarker{id: 14350, var: 436} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x282ff4540.posErrorMarker{id: 14446, var: 428} + <750:1>*0x282892d00.marker{id: 14065, var: 180} + <1100:-0.5, 250:-1>*0x2828941e0.marker{id: 14184, var: 298} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x282fff480.posErrorMarker{id: 14258, var: 352} + <750:1>*0x282891e50.marker{id: 13993, var: 108} + <252:-1>*0x282887de0:UISV-spacing.marker{id: 14290, var: 383} + <248:1>*0x282ff1680.posErrorMarker{id: 14466, var: 360} + <251:1>*0x282ffefa0.posErrorMarker{id: 14234, var: 328} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x282ff0960.posErrorMarker{id: 14328, var: 414} + <251:1>*0x282ff4720.posErrorMarker{id: 14454, var: 453} + <750:1>*0x282ff47e0.negError{id: 14459, var: 345} + <251:1>*0x282ff4660.posErrorMarker{id: 14450, var: 448} + <750:-0.00277778>*UILabel:0x116262a30'إنسخ الكود'.Width{id: 13908, var: 21} + <251:2>*0x282fff8a0.posErrorMarker{id: 14274, var: 370} + <750:1>*0x2828937a0.negError{id: 14124, var: 239} + <750:1>*0x282ffef40.negError{id: 14233, var: 327} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x282fff0c0.negError{id: 14241, var: 335} + <750:1, 251:-1>*0x282fff8a0.negError{id: 14275, var: 371} + <750:-0.00555555>*UILabel:0x116273180'C772'.Width{id: 14033, var: 146} + <1100:1>*0x282890640.marker{id: 13946, var: 62} + <1100:-0.5, 250:-1, 249:-2>*0x2828932f0.marker{id: 14096, var: 210} + <1100:0.5, 750:-2.21875, 252:1, 251:2, 250:2.6, 249:2>*0x2828956d0:UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width.marker{id: 14498, var: 457} + <750:1>*0x2828921c0.slackMarker{id: 14017, var: 133} + <1100:-0.5, 250:-1>*0x282893ca0.marker{id: 14154, var: 269} + <750:-1, 74
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type

Comment: can you provide more details please? Like stack trace, the code snippet causing errors, anything more descriptive

Comment: @FericoSamuel i have edited the description. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

It must be occurring if you haven't relaunched your app after localisation. As soon as you change your app's language and reset the localisation, your app requires a relaunch to function properly..

Comment: i am relaunching but even after that crash is happening

Comment: can u please check the stack trace

Comment: Has your tabbar items also switched from left to right after loaclisation?

Comment: Yes tab bar items are also switched